# How can I select which permission to use when posting to FB

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

My scope in fb login includes 
`$permissions = ["email", "user_about_me", "publish_pages", "publish_actions"];`. But how can I choose which permission to use when posting to timeline or to fb page. I want to used public_pages permission if I want to post to page. I can post as a page only if I remove the publish_actions permission in my scope but I can't post as a user in my timeline.

Comment: _“ can post as a page only if I remove the publish_actions permission”_ – that is definitively not true. Of course you can request publish_actions and publish_pages from the user at the same time. Are you sure you used a page access token when trying to post as the page …?

Comment: yes i used the page id and the page token from me/accounts/ request.

Comment: Are you testing this with a user that has a role in the app? If not, did you get the permissions reviewed yet?

Comment: yes. I already get it. In my function when the data i want post have image or video it uses the user access token. I changed it to page access token.
thanks @CBroe